# AIR 3 Native Extensions - for Java on Windows?

Tags: apache-flex, air

There are a lot of tutorials/details on writing ANE's for Java on Android, but not for Java on Windows. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I thought ANEs on Windows had to be written in C.

Comment: Hi Brian, did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: I think Flextras might be correct, that they have to be written in C/C++/C#, something that provides dll's. The Java ANE's work for Android. Maybe theres a workaround, but I'm sure it would be awkward as....

Answer (score 0):

To package Java code in a native extension on Windows, you would need a C wrapper (using the JNI invocation API).  You might need to distribute a full JVM (though depending on what you know about your target machines, you may be able to assume a JVM and JAVA_HOME defined).